# AJAX получает не те данные

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$.ajax({
  url: "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/http://vm1.culture.ru/abramtsevo/catalog/ajax.php",
  data: {
    PAGEN_1: 1,
    YEAR_SEARCH_LEFT: -99,
    YEAR_SEARCH_RIGHT: 1999,
    TEGS: "Вазы",
  },
  type: 'POST',
});
```

P.S. https://jsfiddle.net/3xLs75t9

Ведь эта функция должна возвращать значения по тегу "Вазы", а возвращает - "Живопись"? Почему?

На самой странице, если посмотреть Network, параметры, вроде как, идентичные: http://vm1.culture.ru/abramtsevo/catalog

Comment: сложно ответить на ваш вопрос так как логика того что вернуть на стороне бекенда и мы ее не видим, и в вашем коде есть ошибка herokuapp.com/ **http://** vm1.culture

Comment: Нет, это не ошибка - это API сервиса cors-anywhere.

Comment: что бы получить вазы `url` должен быть http://vm1.culture.ru/abramtsevo/catalog/ajax.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

На сайте отправляется больше переменных в POST запросе, чем это делаете вы.
Добавьте `"SET-FILTER": "Y"` в `data` и вернутся вам `Вазы`.

https://jsfiddle.net/yjb1sqfk/

Comment: Не знал, как корректно проставить параметр с тире, спасибо!